# uninstall obs after installing Lunar Lobster

Tags: obs-studio

I recently installed Lunar Lobster and OBS will not appear on screen. Should I uninstall and reinstall? If so, should it be done by command line? I'm a new Linux user, so please go easy. Thx

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and run obs from there? Does it crash or give some error message? OBS is quite 'chatty' when it launches, so you may need to read a bit and filter out a lot of the messages to find an actual error.

Comment: file:///home/papakill13/Desktop/CORE DUMPED%3F.png

Comment: file:///home/papakill13/Desktop/Screenshot_20230517_124344.png

Comment: As mentioned, I am brand new at this. The stats box appears, but the actual player does not. It will give the message OBS is already running, however it does not appear on screen.

Comment: ok so posting links to your local computer will not allow anyone to see files on *your local computer*. If you want us to be able to see the files, try adding them to your original post using the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1468242/edit) button.

Comment: Yes please edit information into your question. Thanks. 